# How to adjust a Globalize translation table without breaking app/migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, globalize

I tested a localized rails/react app with the `Globalize Gem`.
Everything locally is working fine.

When I pushed to Heroku I had an error when running `heroku run rails db:migrate` because my migration to create the translation table with  had a mistake:

xxxx_create_translation_table_for_movies

```
class CreateTranslationTableForMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        Movie.create_translation_table!({
                                           :title => :string,
                                           :text => :text
                                       }, {
                                           :migrate_data => true
                                       })
      end

      dir.down do
        Post.drop_translation_table! :migrate_data => true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

when actually the model has an excerpt instead of a text attribute:
schema.rb

```
create_table "movie_translations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "movie_id", null: false
    t.string "locale", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "title"
    t.text "excerpt"
    t.index ["locale"], name: "index_movie_translations_on_locale"
    t.index ["movie_id"], name: "index_movie_translations_on_movie_id"
  end
```

Rails is probably smart enough to run all that locally no problem but of course Heroku is not happy:

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Missing translated field :text
```

I would like to correct my mistake by just swapping `:text => :text` for `:excerpt => :text` but I know that sometimes messing with migrations can break your entire app :D

How could I correct all that in order to push to github again and then to reinstall to heroku? 
Should I create a specific migration to address this issue? Also, will it break the rest of the app that was working fine locally?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you rollback the migrations to that one, change the column name to the correct one and then run `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Good call Mike! I had not thought of it. I will try it and update this post. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mike, it worked. I had to adjust a few things along the way but worked like a charm!

Comment: Nice! Happy to have helped :D